# Understand a proof on Craig's interpolation Theorem

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I am reading Hans Halvorson's [The Craig Interpolation Theorem](https://bit.ly/3SAILWj).

I cannot make the following lines precise:

> We claim now that there is an isomorphism $j: N\mid_{L_0}\to M\mid_{L_0}$ ...
> So, putting the pieces together, we have a model $M$ of $T_\omega\cup U_\omega$.

May I please ask for a rephrased/expanded proof for what happens here? In particular, why

> Indeed, both $N\mid _{L_0}$ and $M\mid_{L_0}$ are models of $T_\omega\cap U_\omega$, which is maximal consistent in $L$.

implies the existence of the isomorphism? Which theorem are we quoting here?

Comment: Your link seems to be broken

Comment: I fixed it by embedding the link in some text. I'm not sure what was wrong, actually. Something about the encoding of the ~.

Comment: @AlexKruckman I think so. Shortening the URL by [Bitly](https://bitly.com/) has worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're missing (and what the author hasn't said) is that both $N|_{L_0}$ and $M|_{L_0}$ are *Henkin* models of $T_\omega\cap U_\omega$. That is, their elements are equivalence classes of constants.

If $T$ is a complete (maximally consistent) Henkin theory, then it has a unique Henkin model up to isomorphism. This is because the equivalence relation on the constants and all the interpretations of the function and relation symbols on the equivalence classes of constants are completely specified by $T$.